# how to set a reconnect value with CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

In my app the message comes to the inque and then is sent to the output queue. We do this thru spring integration. My requirement is if there is a problem in connecting to the output queue then it shud try reconnecting 3 times with a delay of 30  secs and finally if it fails then log the exception. Can you please help on how to achieve this  ? My config file -

```html
<bean id="mqQcfParent" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
<property name="transportType">
<util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP"/>
</property>
<property name="hostName" value="${mq.out.hostname}"/>
<property name="channel" value="${mq.out.channel}"/>
<property name="port" value="${mq.out.port}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="remoteConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
<property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqQcfParent"/>
<property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${mq.out.cacheSize}"/>
<property name="cacheProducers" value="true"/>
<property name="cacheConsumers" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="inQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
<property name="baseQueueName" value="${mq.in.queue}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="aircraftAssignQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
<property name="baseQueueName" value="${mq.out.aircraftAssignQueue}"/>
</bean>
</bean>
<bean id="failureQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
<property name="baseQueueName" value="${mq.out.failureQueue}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageListenerContainerParent" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" abstract="true">
<property name="destination" ref="inQueue"/>
<property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
<property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="${mq.in.max.consumer}"/>
<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${mq.in.min.consumer}"/>
<property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000"/>
<property name="recoveryInterval" value="60000"/>
<property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageListenerContainerCDC" parent="messageListenerContainerParent">
<property name="connectionFactory">
<bean parent="remoteConnectionFactory">
<property name="targetConnectionFactory">
<bean parent="mqQcfParent">
<property name="hostName" value="${mq.in.cdc.hostname}"/>
<property name="channel" value="${mq.in.cdc.channel}"/>
<property name="port" value="${mq.in.cdc.port}"/>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="messageListenerContainerPDC" parent="messageListenerContainerParent">
<property name="connectionFactory">
<bean parent="remoteConnectionFactory">
<property name="targetConnectionFactory">
<bean parent="mqQcfParent">
<property name="hostName" value="${mq.in.pdc.hostname}"/>
<property name="channel" value="${mq.in.pdc.channel}"/>
<property name="port" value="${mq.in.pdc.port}"/>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

```html
<context:property-placeholder location="config/application.properties"/>
<import resource="jms-listener-container-config.xml"/>
<!--   Get Input Messages  -->
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="msgInCDC" channel="toRoute" container="messageListenerContainerCDC" error-channel="errorChannel" acknowledge="transacted"/>
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="msgInPDC" channel="toRoute" container="messageListenerContainerPDC" error-channel="errorChannel" acknowledge="transacted"/>
<!--   Route Messages Depending on Root Element  -->
<int:channel id="toAircraftAssign"/>
<int:channel id="toDiversionChange"/>
<int:channel id="toFlightCreate"/>
<int:channel id="toFlightPlanRelease"/>
<int:channel id="toGateChange"/>
<int:channel id="toPositionReport"/>
<int:channel id="toScheduleChange"/>
<int-xml:xpath-router id="flightUpdateRouter" input-channel="toRoute" default-output-channel="errorChannel" evaluate-as-string="true">
<int-xml:xpath-expression expression="name(/*)"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="AircraftAssignment" channel="toAircraftAssign"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="DiversionChangesUpdate" channel="toDiversionChange"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="CreateFlight" channel="toFlightCreate"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="FlightPlanRelease" channel="toFlightPlanRelease"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="GateChange" channel="toGateChange"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="PositionReportUpdate" channel="toPositionReport"/>
<int-xml:mapping value="ScheduleChangesUpdate" channel="toScheduleChange"/>
</int-xml:xpath-router>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="aircraftAssignMsgOut" channel="toAircraftAssign" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="aircraftAssignQueue"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="diversionChangeMsgOut" channel="toDiversionChange" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="diversionChangeQueue"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="flightCreateMsgOut" channel="toFlightCreate" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="flightCreateQueue"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="flightPlanReleaseMsgOut" channel="toFlightPlanRelease" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="flightPlanReleaseQueue"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="gateChangeMsgOut" channel="toGateChange" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="gateChangeQueue"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="positionReportMsgOut" channel="toPositionReport" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="positionReportQueue"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="scheduleChangeMsgOut" channel="toScheduleChange" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="scheduleChangeQueue"/>
<!--   Error Handling  -->
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="errMsgOut" channel="errorChannel" connection-factory="remoteConnectionFactory" destination="failureQueue"/>
<!--  Logger -->
<int:wire-tap pattern="to*" order="7" channel="wireTapChannel"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="wireTapChannel" level="debug" logger-name="WIRETAP"/>
<!--  Logger  -->
<!--
  <int:wire-tap pattern="to*" order="0" channel="loggerChannel"/> 
-->
<!--
  <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggerChannel" level="DEBUG" expression="'YYYY'"/> 
-->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show any Spring Integration configuration but, presuming you are using a JMS outbound channel adapter, you an add a [retry advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) with an appropriately configured `SimplyRetryPolicy`.

However, if the same broker is being used for the inbound queue too, that session will be broken and the message redelivered anyway; so you might be better off setting the retry policy in the broker.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your time. I have added the spring integration file. Pardon me as I am very new to this. Can you please explain a little bit more what exactly i need to do. Do you have a code sample? that will help me in understanding

Comment: See the [retry-and-more](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) sample app - it shows various configurations for retry; simply add the retry advice to the outbound channel adapters.

Comment: I checked the sample app. There are some nice examples. But the retry-advice is with a service activator. I don't have a service-activator. So when i create the retry template where to call it ?

Comment: Those advices can be added to any consuming endpoint. As I said, simply add `request-handler-advice-chain` a to your JMS outbound adapters. The [ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/ftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/FtpOutboundChannelAdapterSample-context.xml) has another example.

Comment: Great.Thanks a lot Gary.